# Inquirer doesn't wait for input after prompt

Tags: javascript, npm, module, inquirer

For some reason, after prompting, inquirer does not wait for user input and directly moves to the next command line. Here's my code:

```
import inquirer from 'inquirer';

var link;
// const inquirer= require('inquirer');

inquirer
  .prompt([
    {message:"add link", name:"URL"}
  ])
  .then((answers) => {
    console.log(answers);
    // Use user feedback for... whatever!!
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.isTtyError) {
      // Prompt couldn't be rendered in the current environment
    } else {
      // Something else went wrong
    }
  });

import qr from 'qr-image'
import fs from 'fs'
var qr_svg = qr.image(link, { type: 'svg' });

fs.writeFile('user_input.txt',link,(err)=>{
    if(err){throw err;}
})
```

How do I fix this? This is happening even in the node terminal, and vs code. All my packages including node and npm are latest, even the modules are latest. What is causing the issue?

I was trying to generate a prompt, to which the user would reply with a link which would then be printed on screen. Instead, the prompt is generated, and instead of waiting for the input, the control jumps to the new command line.

Comment: Which line of code is the one you don't want to execute yet? Also, i'm guessing the code from `import qr from 'qr-image'` onward is a second file but i don't see how it relates to the first file

Comment: @NicholasTower yeah that part is unrelated as of now. Right now the issue is I need to be able input after the prompt, which isn't happening. The only part I want to execute is the one using inquirer before import qr statement

Comment: The code that imports `qr` down to and including `fsWriteFile...` is synchronous, and executes before the promise returned by `.prompt` is fulfilled  or the `then` handler is called. Also where is the value of `link` assigned?

Comment: @traktor none of that happens. I mean the problem persists even when i removed all code except the inquirer prompt

Answer (score 0):

I'll present a module to create an svg file of a QR code based on the posted code (I wouldn't have known where to start), with some modifications to actually create and save the qr-code asynchronously. Note I was unable to reproduce the problem presented in the post but hope this may provide assistance.

**Setup**

1. Ensure Node and NPM are up to date and upgrade both as needed. If you get warning messages during installs about unsupported NPM or Node versions, come back to this step.
2. Install packages in a (new) working directory of your choice.

   ```
    npm install inquirer
    npm install qr-image
   ```
3. Create a `create-qr.mjs` file in the working directory with the following
   content:

   ```js
   // create-qr.mjs

   import inquirer from "inquirer";
   import qr from "qr-image";
   import fs from "fs";
   import path from "path";

   inquirer
       .prompt([
           {message: "name of qr-code svg", name: "qrName"},
           {message: "URL for qr-code svg", name:"qrHref"}
       ])
       .then((answers) => {
           console.log("answers: ", answers);
           const {qrName, qrHref} = answers;
           const qr_svg = qr.imageSync(qrHref, { type: 'svg' });
           fs.writeFile( path.resolve( qrName+".svg"), qr_svg, (err)=>{
               if(err){throw err;}
           })
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           throw error;
       });
   ```

**Test**

Open a terminal in the working directory an run the module using

```
node create-qr.mjs
```

and enter both "stackoverflow" as the name of the qr code file and "https://www.stackoverflow.com" as the link's href value.

When the module exits (it's not coded to loop), open `stackoverflow.svg` in the working directory and use your smartphone to navigate to the link.

---

**Notes**

- The code above is a simple stand-alone main module presented as an example of manually creating a qr-code: your requirements may be more complicated.
- The svg name question is not expecting an extension, and always produces an svg file in code. Additional questions and validation could be useful if the code is to be distributed.
- Creating and writing the qr code to device storage is moved into the promise chain so they are processed asynchronously after the questions have been asked.
- The `qr.image` method of `qr` returns a readable stream, which `fs.writeFile` doesn't support. The code uses the `qr.imageSync` method as a quick fix because it (`.imageSync`) returns a buffer which `fs.writeFile` does support.
- `path.resolve` resolves a relative path, such as a filename string, against the path of the current working directory.